# How do I enable svn commands from any directory?

Tags: svn, windows-server-2003

I have recently installed SVN on Windows Server 2003. I can execute svn commands in the command prompt if I am in the bin directory (program files\subversion\bin). But trying to execute commands in any other directory results in

'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Where am I going wrong here?

**EDIT**
I checked the Path value in environment variables and it is in there. I added for my user as well as system just in case but no joy?

**EDIT**
Just magically started working. Random

Comment: What might have happened is that you didn't open a new Command Window after installing Subversion.  Changes to PATH will only come into effect in new Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the folder that holds the svn binary to your PATH environment variable.

To do this, hit Windows+Pause, then click the Advanced tab, and the Environment Variables button, and enjoy the horrible editor.

**UPDATE:** Note that the environment works by inheritance, it's not a global "thing" that you edit, think of it as a template that is inherited by every newly started program. So, if you open a command window, type "svn" and get the "not found" error, then edit the path in the dialog descvribed above and try again, nothing will happen.

This is because the command window is working using *its* copy of the environment, which it got when it was started. So, after you change the environment variables, open a new command window and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have ...\subversion\bin in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that folder to the path:

Right click My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables

and edit the Path property to include `program files\subversion\bin`